# Waiter, Get Me A Klatchian Coffee! Or How to Achieve Hyperawareness

Tags: internal-consistency, medicine

**Klatchian Coffee** is the opposite of a Gargle Blaster. It will send you barreling straight into [Caffeine bullet time](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CaffeineBulletTime), that is, speed up your reactions and greatly amplify your thinking powers for the duration of the effect. Sometimes, seeing reality as it really is can be perhaps associated with hilarious nightmare fuel effects, perhaps without.

[image: Klatchian Coffee]

I need me some of that brew. **Are there any real world or imaginable substances that would actually have a similar effect?**

Comment: An appropriate short-story. https://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Inferno_(Chronicle)

Comment: Amphetamines? I did read that USN pilots take it (under doctor supervision!) in order to stay alert during long flights.

Comment: @SJuan76 The US military uses what they call "go pills" our pilots do indeed utilize it, generally on really long flights.

Comment: I would expect such compounds, while possibly increasing awareness of the outside world, would have the side effect of decreasing self-awareness

Comment: The effects you are describing were imagined in the Movie "Limitless", although how the fictional drug was able to produce such an effect was handwaved away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is no - or maybe yes.

The human brain already reacts as fast as is reasonable using the mechanisms available to biology. If introducing a single hormone or substance was able to make it react much faster without serious side effects then it is almost certain that it would already have evolved and we would be using it.

In fact it does already exist. It's called adrenaline. However it mostly speeds up physical reactions through mechanisms like increasing heart rate and blood supply so that the muscles respond more rapidly. That's because your reflexes are already actually pretty damn fast, the limitation is just as much about how fast your body can move. There are all sorts of costs and consequences to keeping adrenaline levels high for a long time though, the human body just can't withstand it.

The only realistic way to achieve what you are looking for would be cybernetics. A computer chip embedded in your brain could do processing and feed the results back, wires run through your body would transmit signals faster than purely biological systems can do so. By performing that sort of drastic alterations and surgery it may indeed be possible to provide super-human capabilities.

Comment: Part of the reason we've evolved to move at the speeds we do is down to the physics of making our bodies move. With the force our muscles can produce and the mass of an average human arm, it takes a certain time - and distance - to accelerate, or to come to a stop. Mess with that and you'd overshoot when reaching for things, or you'd get oscillation in your movements like you see with badly-tuned PID control loops - like [this kitten](https://i.imgur.com/jBtMOLZ.gifv) who hasn't entirely figured out how to stand yet.